Identifying optically active alcohols

The correct option is D only.
I am having a confusion with option B and C. The compound in option B reacts with Grignard to form this

There's only one chiral carbon and thus must be optically active. Same with option C. Then why only option D correct?

This won't survive acidification.

1 equivalent of Grignard reagent reacts with esters to form a ketone, by a nucleophilic substitution mechanism. In this case, $\ce{Ph-}$ will replace the alkoxy group to form methyl phenyl ketone from (B) and ethyl phenyl ketone from (C). 
It is the 2nd equivalent of Grignard reagent that forms the tertiary alcohol. The final products are  from (B) and  from (C) 
As you can see the carbon connected to hydroxyl group is achiral and there are no other stereocentres, hence both alcohols are optically inactive.

OC will melt my brain
